# How to enable Directory Browsing and how to know what web server is in Use?

Tags: http, web

I'm working with Siemens Power Manger Software which have integrated WEB server.

My target is to enable "`Directory listing/browsing`".

My first problem is that i don't know what server Siemens Power Manager uses.

Is there a way to find out?

And is there any option to enable "`Directory listing/browsing`" if I don't know what server this program uses.

I tried with `.htaccess` files but it didn't work.